# What's the point of Babel, Dart, TypeScript, and other JavaScript compilers?

Tags: javascript

So it's been exactly 2 years since I've started learning JavaScript. It's my first programming language. Now, I don't know much about other languages, as my knowledge in C++ is very bare-bones, and I haven't been writing anything else other than the two. But the JavaScript rabbit hole sure goes deep. Things that really confuse me are, firstly, Babel.

What is exactly happening when the browser (Chrome, more specifically) comes across newer JavaScript syntax, like classes, for example? Does it just convert that into a Function constructor with prototype, just like Babel does, or does it read this stuff native? Do people use Babel just to make their apps run on Internet Explorer? Recently I've only been writing ES code and it works awesome in Chrome, and Firefox, so I see no reason to use Babel other than minimize my code.

So recently I've come across Dart, which syntax I really enjoyed. But confusion rose up when I figured out that Dart is also compiling the code you write to JavaScript. Sure, you write a lot less with Dart, but in a YouTube presentation of Dart one guy showed that like 10 lines of Dart code compiles to over 10,000 lines of JavaScript code... How can this be "faster" than vanilla JavaScript, other than just being faster to write? Do people really go to such lengths just to avoid writing JavaScript? I did enjoy Dart, but I called it quits, because the community is non existent. There is only one guy on YouTube that does tutorials, and he just copy/paste everything from the Dart Language Tour, which, in my opinion, is not very well suited for people like me, beginners, I mean. Examples are very bare-bones, and I hate reading documentation, it's so much better to watch live examples, at least for me. So after 2 weeks, I gave up on it.

Other thing I came across, is TypeScript. Now, as far as I figure it, it's the absolute same thing as JavaScript, but with types. I get it, people are used to that. But JavaScript being my first language, I have no problems with it having no types, and I really got used to it. So other than doing Angular (which now you can also do in Dart), I see no point there either.

Or am I just missing something critical? I love vanilla stuff, I still play vanilla World of Warcraft, I really feel like a dad, complaining that the new stuff is just junk compared to the original. So whats the point of going that far, just to avoid writing good old JavaScript? Or are there different reasons for all these compilers and what not...

Thanks!

Comment: So basically your question is about typed vs untyped languages ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ATyped_and_untyped_languages

Comment: Yes, a browser is doing the stuff that it is capable of natively. If it's not capable, it throws an error. That's why we need transpilers for writing new code but running it in old browsers.

Comment: This just reads like a holy war starting argument of "I like JavaScript as it is currently supported by Chrome, what is the point of adding new features or using anything different?"

Comment: "*like 10 lines of Dart code compiles to over 10,000 lines of JavaScript code*" - that's unlikely. At best a malfunction of the compiler to include the entire Dart.js standard library or something.

Comment: The end goal of all programming languages is to run code on the machine. The JavaScript that most browsers support is es5. So other languages compile their code to something the browser understands.

Comment: "*I have no problems with it having no types*" - nope. JavaScript has types, and certainly your programs use types - you need them to argue about the correctness of your program. JavaScript just doesn't spell them out in code, but for larger projects where you cannot infer everything in your head you want to write them down and let your IDE help you.

Comment: @Bergi it was an old video, compiling a Dart class to JavaScript before ES2015 came out I guess. It's probably lesser now, but still, Dart community really needs to start growing, that's the only thing I'd do instead of JavaScript, if it had more video tutorials on all the topics, that is

Comment: It can be difficult to understand why various languages are structured the way they are, when you only speak one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various browsers implement these newer language features at their own "speed", so Chrome for example understands `class`, but Internet Explorer does not.

How Chrome handles this new syntax is not that relevant, you can probably look up the v8 source code for this if you know your way around some heavy C++.

The purpose of Babel is to allow you as a developer to use these features *now* but still be able to serve JS that older browsers understand.

Dart is something else. It's a completely new language with a different goals, comparable speed of execution with the equivalent "native" JS being one of them.

TypeScript is different too. It is, functionally, Babel + strong types.

Why use them?
1) Because some of these new language features are just great (async/await for example can turn a mess of Promises into really nice and readable code).

2) Because some people like writing code for the web in a different paradigm.

3) Because strong typed languages are better suited for some types of problems.

**4) Because anyone can write code that computers understand but few can write code that other humans can understand.**

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. All these answers just brought up more questions for me, but I guess that I haven't yet worked on a project that would make me realize why those things are better than JavaScript, in those specific cases, I mean. Well, I like your answer the most, Sergiu. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

**Babel** - ES6 is widely supported by the main browsers now - but before they did - Babel let you write your code in ES6 and transpile it to ES5 - so it would still work on the older browsers.

But Babel isn't just for transpiling ES6 to ES5. For example - Babel is commonly used to compile [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) to valid javascript code. But you can write babel plugins to do anything - it's basically just a text converter.

**TypeScript** - Typescript gives you features like interfaces, and static typing.

This can be super helpful for writing your code. For example, say I have a method:

```
function addPerson (person) {
     console.log(person.firstname, person.age); 
}
```

and I call it with `addPerson("bob")`, then I'm going to get a runtime error.

Whereas typescript allows me to do something like:

```
interface Person {
    firstName: string; 
    age: number; 
}


function addPerson(person: Person) { 
 ... 
}
```

And then when I try call the function with `addPerson("bob")` typescript will give me a warning in my IDE before I even try run the code.

**Dart** - I don't know.

Comment: Very good explanation on Babel tho. Good job!